# Matlab - Rotation around generic axis

Tags: matlab, rotation

I need to rotate an image around a the y axis using Matlab.

I insert my image in a 3D array and then I apply the transformation matrix using affine3d and imwarp commands.

This is an example:

```
c = cos(theta); s=sin(theta);
ux =0; uy=1; uz=0;
tx =0; ty=0; tz=0;
tt = [(1-c)*ux^2+c (1-c)*ux*uy-s*uz (1-c)*ux*uz+s*uy tx;...
(1-c)*ux*uy+s*uz (1-c)*uy^2+c (1-c)*uy*uz-s*ux ty;...
(1-c)*ux*uz-s*uy (1-c)*uy*uz+s*ux (1-c)*uz^2+c tz; 0 0 0 1];
tform = affine3d(tt);
R = imref3d(size(image));
imrot = imwarp(image,R,tform);
```

In this way I get a rotation around the origin axis, but I want the rotation around the centre of the image so I change the value of ty.

```
ty=128
```

But affine3d wants only [0 0 0 1] as last column.

There is a way to rotate using these commands or do I have to find another way?

Comment: With a quick look at the doc my guess is that you need to use the last *row* to encode a shift, not the last column.

Answer (score 0):

I've answered a very similar question here: [Homographic image transformation distortion issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346525/homographic-image-transformation-distortion-issue/18361795#18361795)

With that answer you can rotate about any axis, and with any point as the origin.

**EDIT**

You can use the Affine matrix form here (with [0 0 0 1] as the last row), you'll just need to add a "1" to each column index (i.e. instead of a <3x3> `R*[x y z]'`, you'll want to do with a <4x4> `R*[x y z 1]`. (Note transpose to make that row a column.)