# Planar Homographies in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, computer-science

I have taken an image in height 2 meters of the ground as the original image and I want to simulate another image in 50 cms of the ground from the scene.

The focal length of camera is 3.7 mm (f = 3.7).

I have used from planar homography H = k'*(eye(3) - ((t*n')/d))*inv(k) for each plane in original image in MATLAB where in the camera coordinate system, x axis is perpendicular to buildings in the right side of the ground, y axis is parallel to the ground, and hence z axis is upward perpendicular to the ground. The origin is camera location in original image and k is 3x3 camera calibration matrix [f 0 0;0 f 0;0 0 1] and t is transfer matrix [0 0 -1.5] and n is normal vector of plane and d is plane distance to the origin and eye(3) is camera rotation.

For example, the plane of the ground has n=[0 0 1] and d = 2. right?

Please guide me about other planes (sky, buildings) implementation in matlab.

My images are [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/16855/planar-homographies-in-matlab).

Comment: See this answer in the DSP forum: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/16855/planar-homographies-in-matlab/16868#16868

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not do it with just one transformation.
But if you know the exact equations of the three planes (i.e. the ground, the left wall, and the right wall) relative to your camera position, and also your camera orientation, then you can do simulate the scene from any given point by applying three different and separate homographies on the three planes.

To do this, at first you need to extract each of the three planes from the image (e.g. img1=extracted ground, img2=extracted left wall, img3=extracted right wall).
Then apply one separate homography to each one of them according to the formula:

```
H=K*R*inv(K) - 1/d * K*t*n'/K
```

You will have three homographies (H1, H2, and H3) corresponding to the three planes.

Note that for each plane you have to set the the n and d according to that plane (The plane is defined as n'*x=d. and x=[x1,x2,x3]' and n=[a,b,c]'). Also take into consideration that t (=translation) and R (=rotation matrix) are adjusted according to the relative position and orientation of the the camera in the current scene and that of camera in the desired (to be simulated) state.

Finally you can render the new image by transforming each plane (img1, img2, and img3) with its own H (H1, H2, and H3 respectively) and then attaching the three images.

You can take a look at my answer in the following question. It explains how to implement the mentioned homography between two planes:

[homographic-image-transformation-distortion-issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346525/homographic-image-transformation-distortion-issue/28331106#28331106)